# fs.readFile derrubando servidor

Tags: node.js, express.js

Estou usando um servidor `node.js` com `express` e criei uma API para que grave o conteúdo que chegou via `POST` em um arquivo `.json`.

Ele faz corretamente o processo até certo ponto: Se o arquivo não existir, ele cria o aquivo na pasta, insere um array em branco e depois chama a função para preencher com o objeto montado que chegou no POST. Em alguma ocasiões ele simplesmente insere outro objeto com o mesmo nome, mesmo tendo sido enviado um objeto com outro nome e cai o servidor.

Outro problema é quando passa pela validação de Objeto existente, que valida pelo item **nome** se existe algum com o mesmo **nome** que chegou, se tiver, ele retorna um json `res.json({ error: 1, message: 'Modelo já existente!' });`. Nesse momento, ele retorna esse json e cai o servidor.

Se puderem me dar uma força, agradeço!

Código:

```js
app.post('/api/salvar_modelo', function (req, res) {

    var nome = req.body.nome_modelo;
    var codigo = req.body.codigo_modelo;

    let jsondata = { 'name': nome, 'model': codigo }
    let archive = 'C:/mnt/modelos/modelos.json';

    let obj = [];
    let json;

    fs.access(archive, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            fs.writeFile(archive, '[]', 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                atualizarJson();
            });
            return
        }
        atualizarJson();
    });

    function atualizarJson() {
        fs.readFile(archive, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ error: 1, message: 'Erro ao salvar modelo!' });
            } else {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log("Entrou ");
                if (obj.length != 0) {
                    obj.forEach(function (objc) {
                        if (objc.name == jsondata.name) {
                            console.log("Entrou 2");
                            res.json({ error: 1, message: 'Modelo já existente!' });
                        }
                    });
                    obj.push(jsondata);
                    json = JSON.stringify(obj);

                    fs.writeFile(archive, json, 'utf8', (err) => {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        res.json({ error: 0, message: 'Modelo salvo com sucesso!' })
                    });
                } else {
                    obj.push(jsondata);
                    json = JSON.stringify(obj);

                    fs.writeFile(archive, json, 'utf8', (err) => {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        res.json({ error: 0, message: 'Modelo salvo com sucesso!' })
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Edit: arrumei o erro dele apagar o conteúdo do arquivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrumado, faltava um callback para que ele não caísse na inserção de objeto quando tem um igual já inserido.

```js
app.post('/api/salvar_modelo', function (req, res) {

    var nome = req.body.nome_modelo;
    var codigo = req.body.codigo_modelo;

    let jsondata = { 'name': nome, 'model': codigo }
    let archive = 'C:/mnt/modelos/modelos.json';

    let obj = [];
    let json;
    // Verifica se o arquivo modelos.json existe, se não existir, cria e insere os dados recebidos como objeto no array
    fs.access(archive, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            fs.writeFile(archive, '[]', 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                atualizarJson();
            });
            return
        }
        atualizarJson();
    });
    // função que faz validaçãos no arquivo modelos.json
    function atualizarJson() {
        // lê o arquivo
        fs.readFile(archive, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ error: 1, message: 'Erro ao salvar modelo!' });
                return;
            } else {
                // verifica se o arquivo já possui algum objeto dentro do array, se já possuir, valida se o nome do objeto já existe na lista
                let exist = false;
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                if (obj.length != 0) {
                    obj.forEach(function (objc) {
                        if (objc.name == jsondata.name) {
                            exist = true;
                            res.json({ error: 1, message: 'Modelo já existente!' });

                        }
                    });
                    // se não existir, insere o objeto no array de objetos
                    if (!exist) {
                        obj.push(jsondata);
                        json = JSON.stringify(obj);

                        fs.writeFile(archive, json, 'utf8', (err) => {
                            if (err) console.log(err);
                            res.json({ error: 0, message: 'Modelo salvo com sucesso!' })
                        });
                    } else { return }
                } else {
                    // se não existir nenhum objeto no array, insere o objeto direto
                    obj.push(jsondata);
                    json = JSON.stringify(obj);

                    fs.writeFile(archive, json, 'utf8', (err) => {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        res.json({ error: 0, message: 'Modelo salvo com sucesso!' })
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```